# Coldfusion Undefined Variables - but they're not

Tags: coldfusion

I hope I'm missing something really obvious here, because for the life of me I can't figure this one out at all!

I have a cfquery with some joins as follows;

```
SELECT f.*, p.ID AS prID, p.product_name, p.shortname, i.newthumb, 
(SELECT AVG(reviewrating) FROM product_reviews AS pr WHERE pr.productid=p.id) AS reviewrating, 
(SELECT description FROM product_descriptions AS d WHERE d.productid=p.id LIMIT 1) AS description
FROM followers_p f
LEFT JOIN products p
ON f.productID=p.ID
LEFT JOIN product_images i
ON i.productid=p.ID
WHERE f.wUserID='#getuser.wUserID#'
ORDER BY f.cID DESC
```

That executes fine and a cfdump of the query shows data is returned as it should be.

Further down the page, I'm running the cfoutput query.  However, it's giving me an error 'Variable NEWTHUMB is undefined. '

I've tried grabbing the image as a subquery with Limit 1 and a few other things, but the result is always the same - cfdump shows the correct data, cfoutput gives an undefined error.

Anything else I can try to figure this one out?  I've noticed a similar issue occurring on another page too.

Edit - the cfoutput code;

```
<cfoutput query="getproductfollow">

    <a href="/#ID#/#shortname#"><img alt="#product_name#" src="#newthumb#"></a>
    <a href="/#ID#/#shortname#">#product_name#</a></span>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Please post your `cfoutput` code

Comment: Yes, show us this: "Further down the page, I'm running the cfoutput query."

Comment: Apologies - I have add the cfoutput code to the original post.

Comment: if you scope your variables does that change anything? instead of you `src="#newthumb#"` does `src="#getproductfollow.newthumb#"` work?

Answer (score 1):

The name of your query isn't in your code, so I can't guarantee this is correct. It seems to be that your error is in your reference to your newthumb variable.

Your query should look like this:

```
<cfquery name="getproductfollow">
    // SQL GOES HERE
</cfquery>
```

Your output should look like this:

```
<cfoutput query="getproductfollow">
    <a href="/#ID#/#shortname#"><img alt="#product_name#" src="#newthumb#"></a>
    <a href="/#ID#/#shortname#">#product_name#</a></span>
</cfoutput>
```

You should show your ENTIRE query, wrapped in the  as well as your .  That would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks Evik, the code you give above is exactly how it looks right now (that is producing the error).

Comment: Put getproductfollow. in front of newthumb : #getproductfollow.newThumb#

Comment: @Lee, please put your <cfdump> in your question. Which version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: OK - some progress made.  I now have it working successfully simply by changing the name of the query and cfoutput query (now reading as getproductfollow2).  I'm still at a loss to explain why this occurred though!

Comment: Lee, is it possible that the reference to #newthumb# is within a second CFLOOP for another query? If so then it is out of scope and @J.T.'s suggestion above should work. Note that #product_name# might also be an issue once the #newthumb# issue is corrected.

Comment: OK - I'm answering my own question here, the answer being - I'm an idiot!

As I mentioned in one of my other comments, it worked when I changed the name of the query.  The reason for this was that I had a query with the same name in a header that was added via cfinclude.

Thanks for all the help in any way - it's very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, we all knew it was an easy fix.

Comment: @Lee, if my answer led to your solution, please select mine as the answer.  If not, please add your solution and select that as the answer.  I'm glad you got your answer!